# SwitchPreference not triggering when pressed

Tags: android

I have the following which creates my settings page with two notification settings:

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**pref_notification2.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="notifications_team_pick"
    android:title="Team Pick Reminders" />


<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="notifications_results"
    android:title="Results Notifications" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I was expecting that the following would be invoked when a notification option is pressed:

```
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        Log.d("Am I: ", "Here");

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            Log.d("Am I: ", "Here 2");
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

However, whatever I attempt I can not get anything to happen once the toggle is pressed.  Any help would be appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

ADDED To Match a Suggestion:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("I am at: ", "OnCreate extends");
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        //Your preference change method code.
        Log.d("I am at: ", "OnCreate extends Hope");
        return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your fragment like this -

```
 package com.accelerate.myprefapplication;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.preference.Preference;
 import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
 import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}


public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.path);
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_team_pick"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_results"));

    }

    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getBoolean(preference.getKey(), true));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        boolean state = Boolean.valueOf(newValue.toString());

        Log.d("Am I: ", "Here");

        return true;

    }
}


}
```

I think this should for you.

Look for this answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the swift response Manmohan, could you please elaborate as I do not fully understand.  Sorry.

Comment: @AlanTingey Please see now.

Comment: I have added your part in BUT nothing happens when I change the toggle :( . Will add my latest code to the question.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, day job got in why.  Will try now.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. You will have to retrieve the value stored after interaction with switch. Use this to retrieve data.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String effchoice = prefs.getString("notifications_team_pick", getString(R.string.default_eff));
```

BTW, Your pref_notification2.xml is wrong. You have not set values to be saved and other things. Like this:

```
<ListPreference
    android:dependency="pref_sync"
    android:key="pref_syncConnectionType"
    android:title="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
    android:entries="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_values"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_syncConnectionTypes_default" />
```

Read  [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: What wont work? the end game is to run some code once a toggle has been pressed.  Why would Manmohan idea not work?

Comment: What do you want to do with preferences? Preferences are made so that you can store app settings and retain them anytime. If you want to show something when the switch is interacted then make that switch in your layout, not in preferences. You will have to re read the value stored when you need that data. Like if you are saving App theme setting (dark or light) then you need to read it when your app starts.

Comment: Oh, looks like I am completely in the wrong ball park.  The end goal is to run a webpage which will update the selection in a mysql database.  Seemed so easy on iOS.  Am I back to the drawing board?

Comment: Yap, you need to add the switch in your layout xml in that case.

Comment: Ok sir, many thanks.  Should I accept your answer as it is evident I was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: It might help the next guy barking up this tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151638/discussion-between-alan-tingey-and-lcukerd).

Comment: @AlanTingey We can work with prefrence change. Please look for ny updated answer. It'll give you way to work efficiently.